# Why does my MongoDB data disappear when I convert my Meteor App to use Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, docker-compose

I recently switched my meteor app to use Docker as I am trying to create a new microservice. Previously, I would deploy my app locally using `meteor run`, but I've switched to `docker-compose up --build` using a docker-compose.yml at the root of my project and a Dockerfile in my Meteor app's directory. I finally got things running, which is great, but all the data I persisted when launching the app via `meteor run` is not being correctly accessed. I know the data still exists because when I try launching the app with `meteor run` the data is restored from the previous sessions.

This leads me to believe I am not connecting to Mongo correctly through Docker, and would appreciate any help finding an answer.

FYI, I am connect to *a mongo instance* it's just a freshly wiped DB.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  aldoa:
    build:
      context: ./js/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
    environment:
      ROOT_URL: ${APP_ROOT_URL:-http://localhost}
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
      PORT: 3000
    volumes:
      - ./opt/app:/./js/app

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    command:
      - --storageEngine=wiredTiger
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db

volumes:
  data:
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you launch meteor using `meteor` or `meteor run` you run in development mode. In that mode, unless you explicitly defined the `MONGO_URL` environmental variable, meteor will start it's own mongo instance on port 3001 (or, to be precise, the meteor port specified with `-p` plus one).

In your docker deployment you are doing the right thing for production and use a separately launched mongo instance running on the default port (27017).

You can export your data from your development instance by running:

```
$ meteor
$ # in a separate terminal:
$ mongodump -p 3001 -d meteor
```

And then import that into the "real" mongo instance:

```
mongorestore /path/to/dump/created/above
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to use --port, but this was very helpful. From now on the "real" mongo instance will be the one on port 27017 :)

P.S. Do you have any experience with volumes in docker-compose? Can't get that working either.

Comment: no, not a docker expert. But those kinds of questions get answered on SO very quickly -- if your specific issue hasn't already been asked and answered before.

Comment: Thanks :) I ended up doing just that! Have a great weekend
...if you are curious:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869063/why-is-meteor-not-installed-inside-my-docker-container