# Why is meteor not installed inside my docker container?

Tags: docker, npm, meteor, docker-compose

I recently switched my meteor app to use Docker as I am trying to create a new microservice. Previously, I would deploy my app locally using meteor run, but I've switched to `docker-compose up --build` using a `docker-compose.yml` at the root of my project and a `Dockerfile` in my Meteor app's directory. I finally got things running, which is great, but I am now trying to build a dev version and I'm running into some trouble.

In my `Dockerfile.dev` I am:

1. Setting the node version
2. Declaring Meteor Version and My App's Code Directory
3. Making a `/src` directory for the container
4. Installing Meteor
5. Copying `package*.json` files to `/src`
6. Install npm packages via `npm install`
7. Copying the My app's source code into `/src`
8. Setting the working directory to `/src`
9. Lastly, running the app with `meteor run`

The dockerfile is running the app, but then my app exits because it cannot find meteor. Which is weird because shouldn't it *have* to find meteor to start the app in the first place? Anyways, I'm lost and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: ./js/myapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
    environment:
      ROOT_URL: ${APP_ROOT_URL:-http://localhost}
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
      PORT: 3000
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    command:
      - --storageEngine=wiredTiger
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db

volumes:
  data:
```

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
# Inspired by: https://github.com/banjerluke/meteor-dockerfile

FROM node:14.17.5 as builder

ENV METEOR_VERSION=2.3.4 \
    APP_SRC_FOLDER=.

RUN mkdir -p /opt/src


RUN echo "\n[*] Installing Meteor ${METEOR_VERSION} to ${HOME}"\
&& curl -s https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION} | sed s/--progress-bar/-sL/g | sh

FROM node:14.17.5-alpine as runner

ENV NODE_ENV=dev

COPY $APP_SRC_FOLDER/package*.json /opt/src/

RUN echo '\n[*] Installing Meteor server NPM dependencies' \
&& cd /opt/src \
&& npm install


COPY $APP_SRC_FOLDER /opt/src/

WORKDIR /opt/src/

CMD ["meteor", "run"]
```

**Error**

```
myapp_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
myapp_1  |   throw err;
myapp_1  |   ^
myapp_1  | 
myapp_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/opt/src/meteor'
myapp_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
myapp_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
myapp_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
myapp_1  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
myapp_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
myapp_1  |   requireStack: []
myapp_1  | }
myapp_myapp_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with `FROM node:14.17.5-alpine as runner` for some reason, this image was causing issues with the launch. Removing it was the key culprit! I got the app successfully running!

The app does launch more slowly than `meteor run` but for now I will take it :)

Comment: I already had problems with alpine distro in Node docker images. Slim works very well ever. Are you preparing this docker compose to put your app in production?

Comment: This is for a dev only environment currently. I understand I'll need to bundle my code for production and have a separate Dockerfile for that. Why? Is there anything else you'd recommend?

Comment: For dev, don't use docker with Meteor, you'll lose reload and other good things. Meteor don't need a docker to dev environment, it already handle all you need.

Comment: I ended up connecting the native meteor dev server to my microservices so it all ended up working really well!